# Find areas of change between rasters in R

Tags: r, if-statement, raster

I have 2 rasters over the same area but in different dates.
What I want is to create a third raster with the changes between the existing rasters.
I want the new raster to has the areas that had value 1 in raster1 but a different value in raster2. I tried the following but I get an error:

```
r3<-ifelse(r1==1 & r2!=1,0,NA)

Error in which(test) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

The rasters have the same number on nrow,ncol,ncell and same resolution.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: Using compareRaster I get :

```
compareRaster(r1,r2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hello have you tried as suggested `compareRaster(r1,r2)` ? Having same size and resolution is not enough. Imagine two photos taken from the same camera of different places in the world ? Be one image slightly shifted from the other would break the compare.

Comment: Hi @Billy34, thanks for your comment! the images are over the same area but on different years.

Comment: Be one image slightly shifted from the other would break the compare. It can also be that the projections differ. Can you add in your question the result of print of your two images ? ie `print(r1)`

Comment: `ifelse` is maybe also the problem. You could compute `r3 <- (r1==1)*(r2!=1)` that would give ones where the test match and zeroes and NA otherwise.